# Geocoding API is not giving Rooftop location even if address is accurate in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to decode an address "344 East Columbia Avenue, Pomona, 91767, CA" but it gives me Location type as Range_interpolated

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "344",
               "short_name" : "344",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "East Columbia Avenue",
               "short_name" : "E Columbia Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pomona",
               "short_name" : "Pomona",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Los Angeles County",
               "short_name" : "Los Angeles County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "91767",
               "short_name" : "91767",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "3952",
               "short_name" : "3952",
               "types" : [ "postal_code_suffix" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "344 E Columbia Ave, Pomona, CA 91767, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.0684616,
               "lng" : -117.7472136
            },
            "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.0698105802915,
                  "lng" : -117.7458646197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.0671126197085,
                  "lng" : -117.7485625802915
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "EikzNDQgRSBDb2x1bWJpYSBBdmUsIFBvbW9uYSwgQ0EgOTE3NjcsIFVTQSIbEhkKFAoSCVf7or0HLsOAEaYT6OuR5xZiENgC",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Whereas on searching the same address in Google Maps, it is showing me location accurately.

Whereas on decoding "343 East Columbia Avenue, Pomona, 91767, CA" address gives me Rooftop location type.

As per Google documentation, [Range_interpolated](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.1.3/javadoc/com/google/maps/model/LocationType.html)  indicates that the returned result reflects an approximation (usually on a road) interpolated between two precise points (such as intersections). Interpolated results are generally returned when rooftop geocodes are unavailable for a street address.

Does anyone have an idea on accuracy of the Range_interpolated location type? How much accurate location it provides in meters?

Comment: There is no defined accuracy for RANGE_INTERPOLATED results.  Per the documentation that means is rooftop geocodes are unavailable for that street address (which I agree is strange, as that is the only house on that block that doesn't have a ROOFTOP result).  What do you mean by "Whereas on searching the same address in Google Maps, it is showing me location accurately", is it different from the result returned by the Geocoder?

Comment: @geocodezip Searching the 344 E Columbia Ave address in Maps (refer [link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/344+E+Columbia+Ave,+Pomona,+CA+91767,+USA/@34.0684616,-117.7481012,18z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c32e07bda2fb57:0xdbb7a265157f782e!8m2!3d34.0684616!4d-117.7472136)) is showing the precise Block level (344 E) whereas searching the cordinates provided in Geocode API ([link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/34%C2%B004'06.5%22N+117%C2%B044'50.0%22W/@34.0684616,-117.7483079,18z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d34.0684616!4d-117.7472136)) is showing result for 342 E block.

Comment: The geocoder/reverse geocoder show the same behavior as Google Maps (and the same location, best I can tell).  Why do you think Google Maps is showing you the location accurately (or differently from the API)?